# How do I access the DOM tree of a page from a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit, webview

How do I access the DOM tree of a page from a WebView?
Apple's documentation is not clear about this, should I use `WebScriptObject`? how?

Comment: What platform? OS X or iOS? Note that if it's the latter, then the answer is going to be "you can't".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about on the desktop, you can call `-[WebView mainFrameDocument]` to get the `DOMDocument` corresponding to the main frame (this is the same thing as `[[WebView mainFrame] DOMDocument]`. This object is the same thing as `document` in JavaScript.